# How to randomly change value of string array?

Tags: android, arrays, random

I have made a string array with some names, now I want to change the order of the values and then use a for-loop. my only problem is that I don't know how to change the array values order. here is my code :

## This is the array:

```
people = new ArrayList<>();

people.add("Sam");
people.add("John");
people.add("Kim");
people.add("Edison");
```

### "text" is my textview and "people" is my array with 4 values. I have tried this:

```
int rando = (int)(Math.random() *4);
for (i=0; i< people.size(); i++) {
text.append(people.get(rando));
}
```

but it only prints one of the values four times. Like this:

KimKimKimKim

Comment: That's because `rando` never gets a different value other than the one it gets **outside** the loop. And even if it was set **inside** the loop (as it should), you will most likely get some duplicate value. Eventualy, **all** of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Collections.shuffle(people);` to get the shuffled names from the arraylist. One line code should do the trick you're looking for

```
textView.setText(TextUtil.join(",", Collections.shuffle(people));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method

```
public static String getRandom(String[] people) {
   int rnd = new Random().nextInt(people.length);
   return people[rnd];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.This is how I shuffeled songs in my music player app

```
for (i=0; i< people.size(); i++) {
shuffleText(people.size())
}
private void shuffleText(int size) {
      int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt((size) + 1) + 1;
      text.append(people.get(randomNumber));
  }
```